# Common MVC _layout pages(Master page) for multiple websites

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, web, master-pages

Is it possible to use a common layout page in MVC for multiple websites??

I have to use one layout page and i need to create multiple solutions of website and use the same layout page in all other websites

Comment: [How to use common Layout and styles across multiple Asp.net MVC applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422194/how-to-use-common-layout-and-styles-across-multiple-asp-net-mvc-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use add existing item in visual studio add them as a link that way you will need to change only one file.